# How to create the structure file for these materials?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I want to create a POSCAR or CIF file file for the monolayers with the data mentioned in the table below :

[image]

Knowing that the spacegroup is : R-3 (148)

Could you please create the POSCAR/CIF for these 3 monolayers and show me the way you did it?

Reference paper : https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.103.075433

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- MoI3:

Ref: http://www.2dmatpedia.org/2dmaterials/doc/2dm-699

Monolayer MoBr3 and MoCl3 can be obtained by modifying the structure of MoI3 with the provided parameters.

- 2D materials database:

Ref: http://www.2dmatpedia.org/query?collection=2dmaterials&search_string=top-down

- Related:

[Reliability about the predicted two-dimensional crystal structures based on DFT high-throughput calculation?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/reliability-about-the-predicted-two-dimensional-crystal-structures-based-on-dft)